# how convert here URL to String in java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;`enter code here`


public class Mover {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {



        URL source = Mover.class.getResource("host"); 
        source.toString();
        String destino = "C:\\users\\jerso\\desktop\\";


Path sourceFile = Paths.get(source,"hosts");//here an error occurs.
Path targetFile = Paths.get(destino,"hosts");

Files.copy(sourceFile, targetFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    enter code here

}
}
```

I Don't know what to do here->>Path sourceFile = Paths.get(source,"hosts");
The method get(String, String...) in the type Paths is not applicable for the arguments (URL, String.

Comment: What error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target could be composed as:

```
Path targetFile = Paths.get("C:\\users\\jerso\\desktop", "hosts");
```

Solution:

```
URL source = Mover.class.getResource("host/hosts"); 
Path sourceFile = Paths.get(source.toURI());
Files.copy(sourceFile, targetFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Better (more immediate):

```
InputStream sourceIn = Mover.class.getResourceAsStream("host/hosts"); 
Files.copy(sourceIn, targetFile,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Mind that `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` use relative paths from the package directory of class `Mover`. For absolute paths: `"/host/hosts"`.

Comment: I did that now comes the erro
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
 at pergunta.Mover.main(Mover.java:15)

Comment: If `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` return null, then the path to the resource is incorrect. Open the jar (zip format) and check the path (must be case-sensitive).

Comment: I just want move an file into jar to C:Program Files but I dont know.

Comment: A jar is in zip format, so it can be opened in several ways; like with 7zip. Then you can at least verify an absolute path "/host/hosts".

Answer (score 1):

Calling `toString()` on source does not change the memory reference to now point to a string; `toString()` *returns* a string. What you're looking for is this:

```
Path sourceFile = Paths.get(source.toString(),"hosts");
```

Good luck!

Comment: Except, the string form of a URL is not a valid Path, so that method call will fail.